# Jackson XmlMapper not converting list values

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a case, xml string need to be convert as json string, code is below. List is not converting as List in JSON, last entry only present in the output.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
  JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree("<Find Status=\"Success\"><Result><Provider><lastUpdated>1545391251168</lastUpdated><connection><entityType>CIMHTTPGETRequest</entityType><entityId>M7IH6HVWAAAAU74VJ5F5PBJZ</entityId></connection><connection><entityType>CIMHTTPGETRequest</entityType><entityId>M7IH6HWBAAAAU74VJ7KW72FB</entityId></connection><connection><entityType>CIMHTTPGETRequest</entityType><entityId>M7IH6HWCAAAAU74VJ4TQATY4</entityId></connection></Provider></Result></Find>".getBytes());
  ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  System.out.println(jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(node));
}
```

**Actual output is:**

> {"Status":"Success","Result":{"Provider":{"lastUpdated":"1545391251168","connection":{"entityType":"CIMHTTPGETRequest","entityId":"M7IH6HWCAAAAU74VJ4TQATY4"}}}}

**Expected output is:**

> {"Status":"Success","Result":{"Provider":{"lastUpdated":"1545391251168","connection":[{"entityType":"CIMHTTPGETRequest","entityId":"M7IH6HVWAAAAU74VJ5F5PBJZ"},{"entityType":"CIMHTTPGETRequest","entityId":"M7IH6HWBAAAAU74VJ7KW72FB"},{"entityType":"CIMHTTPGETRequest","entityId":"M7IH6HWCAAAAU74VJ4TQATY4"}]}}}

**Dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: According to your XML your generated JSON should have several `connection` objects each with only one `entityType`/`entityId` pair

Comment: Yeah that is the problem, how to fix it.

Comment: I mean your expected output in question is incorrect

Comment: @Ivan- that is the list, how can you create list xml? i think that is correct only. You can past that XML in any online converts you can see my expected output.

Comment: Check the gist on the this [link](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/205), it should help.

Comment: @m4gic: thanks for your comment, that helped me.